# Как мне начать выполнять функцию PHP заново с исправленными переменными или же вставить возможные переменные?

Tags: php, функции

Вопрос уже задавался, но никакого нормального ответа не дали( Наверное вопрос глупый, прошу заранее за него прощения)

Никак не могу разобраться как сделать, так чтобы выполнять функцию заново если $key не подходит, это скрипт дешифровки AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding как мне реализовать скрипт, если key не подошел, он начнет подставлять key2 например и так далее? Или как мне подсказали что нужно подставить массив из возможных ключей, но я не понял куда нужно подставить, помогите пожалуйста(

```
function decrypt($key, $value)
{
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
        $RES = $value;
    } else {
        $decoded_value = urldecode($value);
//Convert Base64URL to Base64 by replacing "-" with "+" and "_" with "/"
        $b64 = strtr($decoded_value, '-_', '+/');
        $result = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($b64), "AES-128-ECB", hex2bin($key), OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
        $validation_regex = "/^(\d)+((\.)\d+)?\_/";
// Check that the decrypted value is valid
        if (preg_match($validation_regex, $result) == 0) {
            throw new Exception('Decrypted value is not valid!');
        }
        list($RES, $b) = explode("_", $result);
    }
    return $RES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что в предыдущих комментариях Вам советовали использовать нечто такое:

```php
$value = "some-value";
$keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"];

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    try {
        $res = decrypt($key, $value);
        break;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        // Следующий ключ
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Супер, вы просто лучший! Спасибо, что проходили мимо и решили заглянуть)))